# PHP accessing DateTime object properties

Tags: php, object

I have problems getting the date from a `DateTime` object. I use code like `print_r($value->created_at)` and it shows me

```
DateTime Object 
( 
    [date] => 2018-03-10 12:53:18.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1 
    [timezone] => +02:00 
) tablet
```

Now how to get this `[date]`? I tried with different ways like `$value->created_at->date` and `$value->created_at["date"]` but it does not work out.

Comment: Already said that doesn't work.
Undefined property: DateTime::$date

Comment: $date = $value->created_at;echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: Your object is a `Datetime object`, use `$value->created_at->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: What error are you getting. Please show us the FULL error message

Answer (score 3):

The names in the `[]` are the names of the objects properties so

```
$value->created_at->date
$value->created_at->timezone_type
$value->created_at->timezone
```

are the only properties available to you

Example

```
$d = new DateTime('now');
print_r($d);

echo $d->date . PHP_EOL;
echo $d->timezone_type . PHP_EOL;
echo $d->timezone . PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2018-03-29 11:17:19.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
2018-03-29 11:17:19.000000
3
UTC
```

If you want convert the date to be a specific format then you can use the `->format()` method like this

```
echo $d->format('d/m/Y h:s');
```

Result

```
29/03/2018 11:37
```

Comment: Accessing those properties directly is rather dangerous though, try to echo date before doing a print_r on `$d` and it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChristianM Agreed, but as OP was trying that I thought I would start there and then gently introduce the `->format()` functionality

Comment: You are right of course :) I just tend to avoid showing ungood example code, because in a hurry someone might just copy paste that :D

Answer (score 2):

This is a `\DateTime` object http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

You can get a string representation of the date as you see when var_dumping by using the format method:

```
$value->created_at->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Note that I used the ISO8601 format, you can give any format string you want or use one of the predefined ones, depending on how you want to use this string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this ways,

```
$date = $value->created_at;
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```